# Como fazer transição de telas programaticamente com Swift?

Tags: swift, transição

Boa noite, pessoal. Estou tentando fazer umas transições de tela programaticamente com swift, mas não consigo. Tentei usar o navigationController, mas não funcionou, sempre dá um erro diferente. As telas estão dispostas em um mesmo storeboard, só preciso passar da tela 1 para a tela 2. Tentei usar protocolos também, mas não consegui e ainda fiquei mais enrolada. Segue abaixo o código que estou tentando usar para fazer a mudança de tela, esse trecho está no ViewController:

```
@IBAction func btnSegue() {
    let newTela = TelaDoisViewController(delegate: self)

    if let navigation = navigationController {
        navigation.pushViewController(newTela, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando `NavigationController`:

```
@IBAction func chamarNavigationController() {
   let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let novoNavigation = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavViaCodigo")
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(novoNavigation, animated: true)
}

// voltar pro navigation anterior
@IBAction func voltarProNavigationAnterior() {
   navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Se estiver usando `ViewController`:

```
@IBAction func chamarViewController() {
  let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let novoViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewViaCodigo")
  self.presentViewController(novoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// voltar pro viewController anterior
@IBAction func voltarPraViewAnterior() {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

*ps.:* Fiz um exemplo de como fazer essas transições usando `Segue` e `programaticamente` caso queira dar uma olhada >> [Exemplo do código.](https://github.com/iTSangarDEV/ExemploTransicoes)

Answer (score 1):

Para você usar a navigation a ViewController precisa estar "dentro"de uma navigation.

Mas se voce quiser simplesmente mostrar outra view voce pode usar o seguinte código:

```
let vc = ViewController() //Aqui você vai estanciar a sua ViewController de destino.
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```